# SQL - Distribute rows from a table into uneven groups, based on another table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Suppose I have the table People:

```
name | group
------------
bob  | -
bill | -
joe  | -
tim  | -
mei  | -
jen  | -
ben  | -
lyn  | -
eli  | -
fin  | -
hal  | -
kim  | -
```

And table Groups:

```
group | max_people
------------------
A     | 2
B     | 5
C     | 3
```

How would I write a query that returns rows from the People table with each row sequentially assigned to a group, until all 10 people are assigned.

The number of people assigned to a group cannot exceed the max_people value of said group. So if all the group's max's have been reached, remaining people should be left unassigned.

So the output should look like:

```
name | group
------------
bob  | A
bill | A
joe  | B
tim  | B
mei  | B
jen  | B
ben  | B
lyn  | C
eli  | C
fin  | C
hal  | -
kim  | -
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Tables don't have order to their rows. So what does "sequentially" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number your names, e.g.

```
select name, row_number() over (order by name) as num
from names
```

Assign number ranges to your groups:

```
select 
  grp, 
  sum(max_people) over (order by grp) - max_people + 1 as from_num,
  sum(max_people) over (order by grp) as till_num
from groups
```

Combine the two:

```
select n.name, g.grp
from
(
  select name, row_number() over (order by name) as num
  from names
) n
left join 
(
  select 
    grp, 
    sum(max_people) over (order by grp) - max_people + 1 as from_num,
    sum(max_people) over (order by grp) as till_num
  from groups
) g on n.num between g.from_num and g.till_num;
```

Comment: While all the answers worked, this was the simplest/most straight forward method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a cursor on people table

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50),@groupname varchar(10)  

DECLARE people_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM people
 OPEN people_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM people_cursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       select top 1 @groupname = group from groups table where max_people>0  
       update  people set group =  @groupname where name = @name

       update group  set  max_people= max_people -1 where group =  @groupname 

       FETCH NEXT FROM people_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE people_cursor
DEALLOCATE people_cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you could duplicate groups base on value of max_people column like this

```
WITH Repeater (Repeat ) AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Repeat UNION ALL
    SELECT Repeat + 1 FROM Repeater WHERE Repeat < 99
),
GroupsRepeat AS (
    SELECT [group], max_people,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [group] ASC) AS row_num
    FROM  Groups INNER JOIN Repeater ON Groups.max_people >= Repeater.Repeat    
)
```

Then, you could join defined GroupsRepeat table with People table like the following

```
SELECT People.name, 
          COALESCE(GroupsRepeat.[group], People.[group]) AS [group] 
   FROM   (SELECT *, 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [group]) AS row_num 
           FROM   People) People 
          LEFT JOIN GroupsRepeat 
                 ON GroupsRepeat.row_num = People.row_num;
```

You could see a demo [here](http://rextester.com/CARXF57547)